# Nuget package installation fails although package should be supported

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, nuget

I am trying to install the package [Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions/1.0.0) in my Visual Studio 2013 solution as part of a Sitecore installation. The solution has .NET target framework 4.5.2.

The installation fails with

> Install-Package : Could not install package 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions 1.0.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 
>   '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the 
>   package author.
>
> At line:1 char:1
>   + Install-Package Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions -Version 1 ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand

I have tried performing the installation in a completely new, empty solution but the installation still fails.

According to the link, there is a dependency to .NETStandard 1.0 but this should be supported by 4.5 according to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard).

Comment: Do you have `(with .NET Core 1.x SDK)` installed?

Comment: Yes, I do. This one: https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/download-archives/1.0.5-download.md

Comment: Out of curiosity, what version of Nuget are you running? I believe there is a version of 2.12 for VS 2013 that supports .Net Standard but unless it is installed, it doesn't recognize the netstandard moniker by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JaCraig's commment helped me solve this: I upgraded Nuget Package Manager from 2.8 to 2.12. Afterwards, there were no problems with the installation.